# iWork Numbers evaluate string

Tags: iwork, numbers

I have a cell with the following content `2262/4121`. I want to have a cell next to it that contains the result of that expression. Is there a function for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the VALUE() function for that. Its only argument is the cell that you want to evaluate

From the documentation:

> The VALUE function returns a number value, even if the argument is formatted as text. This function is included for compatibility with tables imported from other spreadsheet apps.
>
> `VALUE(source-string)`
>   source-string: Any value.
>
> Notes
>   You’ll never need to use the VALUE function in a new table, because numbers in text are automatically converted for you.
>
> Only the formatted text is converted. For example, if you type the string $100.001 into a cell, the default format will display only two decimals ($100.00). If VALUE refers to this cell, it will return 100, the value of the formatted text, not 100.001.
>
> **If the argument can’t be returned as a number value (does not contain a number), the function returns an error.**
>
> Examples
>   `=VALUE(“22”) returns the number 22.`
>
> `=VALUE(RIGHT(“The year 1953”, 2)) returns the number 53.`

Comment: It only works if the source text cell contains a mathematical expression in the form of "a/b". Any other operator such as +-* fails. Also multiple operands such as "a+b+c-d+e-f+g" are not possible.

I would like to have my source text cell with i.e. "1+2+3-4+5-6.7+8.99" and another cell evaluating the content of that source cell.

Comment: Anyone with a solution for evaluating a cell with multiple arbitrary operands?

Answer (score 0):

In the general case you're stuck. But in a special case you might be able to do something. To add up a column of inconveniently formatted numbers, I wrote a formula that uses two other formulas to extract intermediate values from the text:

```
  input       number   scale    answer
88315.0 KB   88315.0       1    88,315
 119.52 MB    119.52    1024   122,388
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but could you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/364748/edit) it to include the actual formula you've written? Otherwise this won't really help other users.